# Django why my static JS files not loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-templates

I have a django project I am working on, and I am pretty new to Django and Python in general. I have created my base.html as the following:

```
{% load adminlte_helpers i18n %}
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% include 'adminlte/lib/_styles.html' %}
    {% endblock %}


{% block body %}
   ....
{% endblock body %}

{% block javascript %}
{% include 'adminlte/lib/_scripts.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

After that I have created my _scripts.html file as the following:

```
{% load static %}
{% block scripts %}
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %} "></script>

{% block datatable_js %}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now I want to to add in a new html file named example.html a chart created with charts.js. Now I have created it and added in the example.html. But If I try to created a new js file (named graph.js) in my static folder does not work. 
In which part of my code I have to insert `<script src="{% static "grafici/graph.js" %}"></script>` to load it correctly?

this my setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT= '/static/'
```

Comment: nobody could help me?

Comment: make sure you have this ```grafici``` folder inside your ```/static/``` directories. And also add this ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')``` line to your ```settings.py``` if you want use ```collectstatic```.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this CMD
"""
python manage.py collectstatic
"""

Comment: OKey @Zouhair Jabiri thanks, but in which part of my code I have to add my `<script src="{% static "grafici/graph.js" %}"></script>`